# How to get elements out of a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example supposedly I have a list like this:

```py
name = ['John','Geoffrey','Travis']
```

How do I transform this list to something like:

```
John
Geoffrey
Travis
```

Comment: What are you intending to *do* with the names you get from the list? There are a variety of ways to get one or all of the values out of a list, but your example of what you want isn't clear. Is that supposed to be printed output? Or is it supposed to represent doing something with each name one at a time?

Answer (score 2):

This will [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the elements using a space and a newline character as the separator.

```py
name = ['John','Geoffrey','Travis']
s = str.join(' \n', name)
print(s)
'''
John
Geoffrey
Travis
'''
```

Comment: See the updated version of the question, Indeed OP wanted the items below each other but because of the markdown stuff, they seemed they are in a row.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to get elements out of a list in Python you can just name a variable that has those elements so that they aren't listed.

```
name = ['John', 'Geoffrey', 'Travis'] # Giving a list some elements
print(name)
# Now changing this so that its all together and not bound to a list that prints every element with brackets
names = "John Geoffrey Travis" # Putting all elements together in a variable 
print(names)
```

Please correct me if I didn't answer your question correctly, it was pretty difficult to understand what you meant by how you explained what you want to do with your code.

Comment: This example is not helpful, because it is specific and not generic. The OP is looking for a way to create a string containing the elements of ANY list, not a single, specific list.